# OAuth2: using PKCE instead of client_secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, pkce

I have a web app that uses OAuth2's [Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) to authenticate.

I'd like to be able to keep my session active for a long time, using refresh tokens. But since I can't securely store a client_secret in a web app, I can't use the traditional [Authorization Code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).

Is it safe to use [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) in place of the client_secret, or am I losing some level of security in doing so?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. While PKCE is more secure than NOT using it; the Implicit Grant with PKCE still leaves the Access Token may be exposed to the Resource Owner and perhaps other applications residing on the same device.

PKCE primarily protects from when the attacker intercepts the authorization code  returned from the authorization endpoint within a communication path not protected by Transport Layer Security (TLS).

Implicit Flow is only suitable for OAuth Client applications that are browser based or JavaScript **NOT** Mobile Devices or other Applications that could use a Authorization Code Grant

Comment: Why couldn't JavaScript apps use the Auth Code grant with PKCE?

Comment: You can. Assuming you are using a "public client" which are susceptible to the  authorization code interception attack. If you are using a confidential client and TLS and a nonce properly, I am not sure there is a gain in security.

Comment: FYI: This might be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/appauthhelper

Answer (score 0):

With implicit grant, you can use neither PKCE, nor refresh tokens. If you want to improve security, then you should add a back-end to your web application, which can store a `client_secret` (or use an alternative method of client authentication). PKCE would not be needed.

Comment: But what about using the Authorization Code grant with an empty secret? Would PKCE be sufficient to replace the secret, since that couldn’t be securely stored? Adding a back end would require a separate authentication process and session to protect it, and I wanted to only use OAuth for authentication.

Comment: PKCE serves as proof of possession of the authentication code to protect against authentication code interception attacks. It CANNOT be used for client authentication, because ANY client (even a malicious one) can send an authentication code challenge with the authentication request. @JW.